# Eliminate consecutive two dots

Tags: validation, validation-rule

How to eliminate consecutive two dots in validation rule and 1st char should not be . [dot]

example:

- sal..esforce  - invalid
- sal.esforce  - valid
- .salesforce  - invalid
- salesforce.  - valid

Current Rule:

```
AND(ISCHANGED(Status__c),OR(
NOT( REGEX( State_Country__c 
, "[a-zA-Z0-9-_]*")), 

CONTAINS(LEFT( State_Country__c , 1), "_"),

CONTAINS(LEFT(State_Country__c , 1), ".")


)
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex might be causing you issues

I've had a go at changing this. It should pass your criteria, if not let me know

`^(?!.*\.\.|\.).*$`

[Demo of it here with your listed criteria](https://regex101.com/r/elLjzV/2)

Comment: I'd think `^\\.+|(?>\\w\\.{2,}\\w?)` would probably be a better regex here. Captures cases with 1 or more dots at the beginning, or 2+ dots in between word characters (including at the end of the string). The `?>` makes the group non-capturing, and the double backslashes are to appease Salesforce.

Comment: You might also want to go into more detail about how this regex would fit in to OP's validation rule

Answer (score 1):

One simple format should be

```
OR(CONTAINS(State_Country__c, '..'), LEFT(State_Country__c, 1) == '.')
```